# "Cannot find the driver in the classpath!" aws beanstalk connecting to mysql on aws RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, classpath, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently been trying to set up a backend service for a mobile app using AWS. I need to have a SQL database and a webservice which can take requests, search database and return the results for the app to read.

I was able to set up the MySQL separately and was even able to make a connection via MySQL workbench and a local server (through JDBC).

I set up a webservice with a tomcat environment, downloaded their sample code (available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html  under Java with Tomcat) and added their JDBC code to the main jsp (available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html).

I was not able to get the code to work, I even made another RDS through the beanstalk console and yet it didnt work. Right now I am getting this error. I have my stacktrace below.

I couldnt find any solution online. What I figured is that the mysql jar library isnt recognized by the environment and I am not sure how to add it. In eclipse and intellij its easy since you can do it through menus. I tried editing the manifest file and the .classpath file but none of those worked. So im stumped.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 121

118:     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
119:     System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
120:   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
121:     throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
122:   }
123: 
124:   Connection conn = null;


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:578)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find the driver in the classpath!
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:232)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:229)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```